# facebook exception on login - "The proxied app is not already installed"

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login

When attempting to login after the user presses a button I get the exception listed below. We are on android facebook 3.21.0. The exception occurs as the facebook login prompt appears. I get a callback that it is in the opening state, but never the opened state. The login ultimately works, as if I do a cold boot the user is logged in. But the process never completes on our first session, and the actions we want to take when we get the 'opened' state aren't being started.

I've looked at a few of the other reports of this issue and the responses I have seen don't really apply for us. Any thoughts? Any additional info I could provide?

```
private static final String[] sPermissionsRead = new String[] { "public_profile"}; 

public void Login( boolean showLogin )
{
    // First just check if there is an active session.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();       
    if ( Consts.DEBUG ) Log.d( Consts.TAG, "<<< FACEBOOK >>> Login called: session = " + session );

    if( showLogin && !session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed())
    {
        // With user interaction, so create a new session, set it as the active session and attempt to open for read with the required permissions
        session = new Session( mActivity );
        if ( Consts.DEBUG ) Log.d( Consts.TAG, "<<< FACEBOOK >>> Login called: created new session: " + session );
        Session.setActiveSession( session );

        if ( Consts.DEBUG ) Log.d( Consts.TAG, "<<< FACEBOOK >>> openForRead called" );
        session.openForRead(  new OpenRequest(mActivity).setCallback(sessionStatusCallback).setPermissions(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(sPermissionsRead))) );
    }
    else
    {
        if ( Consts.DEBUG ) Log.d( Consts.TAG, "<<< FACEBOOK >>> OpenActiveSession called" );
        // No user interaction, so just try to open an active session using the cached token
        Session.openActiveSession(mActivity, showLogin, sessionStatusCallback );
    }
}
```

**StackTrace**

```
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443): Exception during service
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: [code] 408 [message]: The proxied app is not already installed. [extra]: null
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:84)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:163)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponse.h(ApiResponse.java:188)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.platform.auth.server.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:275)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.platform.auth.server.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:31)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.a(ApiResponseHandler.java:55)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.handleResponse(ApiResponseHandler.java:28)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:699)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:206)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.d(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:159)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:314)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:527)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:251)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:20)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.platform.common.server.SimplePlatformOperation.a(SimplePlatformOperation.java:39)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.platform.common.server.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:59)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.e(BlueServiceQueue.java:360)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:58)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:280)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at com.facebook.common.executors.ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.run(ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.java:58)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-21 15:53:47.855: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9443):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```